# Data mining approaches for analysis of sequential data with nominal attributes

Tags: clustering, classification, data-mining, ordinal-data

Question for the experienced data miners out there:

#### Given this scenario:

- There are N shopping carts
- Each shopping cart is filled with an arbitrary number of M items from an infinitely large set (with the current amount of data I have, that arbitrary number can hit numbers around 1500)
- The order in which each cart is filled is significant
- There are other attributes such as geolocation of shopper, but these can be (and currently are) thrown out in favor of making the algorithm simpler

#### I need to:

- At a particular point in time, given only the ordered sets of items in each cart, identify 'similar' carts without prior knowledge of class labels
- After a certain amount of data has been collected and a drudge works through the data and assigns labels, create a classifier that can work quickly with future unseen data

#### Initial approach:

- So far, my approach has been focused on the first point. My method uses k-means clustering and handles the sequential nature of the data by using a distance matrix generated by calculating the Hamming distance between carts. In this way, [apple, banana, pear] is different from [pear, apple, banana], but [apple, banana, pear] is less different from [apple, banana, antelope]. The appropriate value of k is determined through investigation of the silhouette coefficient. The clusters generated from this seem to make sense, but the runtime of my method will definitely be prohibitive as my dataset scales.

#### Question:

- Would anyone happen to have any suggestions for a novice data miner for this problem?

#### Edits with more info:

- I've found suggestions that consider using n-gram features and comparing them pair-wise. A concern I have about this is order: will the order of the sequences be maintained if n-gram models are used? Also, I see performance issues being a larger possibility with this method.

Comment: Interesting question, but probably better suited for [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I originally submitted this to stats.stackexchange.com and am viewing it from there...is this showing up elsewhere?

Comment: Oh, man, it has been a long week. I habitually open a bunch of StackOverflow and CrossValidated questions in adjacent tabs, and this was at the end of a string of StackOverflow questions. Then, when I flagged for attention, it gave me the option to suggest that it move to stats.stackexchange - except that was actually META.stats.stackexchange. I should probably go to bed now.

Comment: you don't sound like a novice data miner to me.

Comment: @rolando2: I suppose it's all relative, heh. I still feel like I've only scraped the surface of the subject...

Answer (score 1):

I am a novice data miner as well, but may I suggest that exploratory data analysis is always a good first step?  I would see if items can be assigned some sort of 'priority value' which can serve to predict how early they appear in the cart, as such a result may allow you to use simpler models.    Something as simple as a linear regression on (#order in cart/#number of items in cart) for all carts possessing item X will give you an idea of whether this is possible.  Suppose you find that a certain proportion of items always appear early, or later, and some seem to be completely random: this would guide you in your later model-building.